# Simple form submission redirect to wrong page, why?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, forms, http-post

I can't understand this behaviour in Google App Script, can someone explain?

This is a very simple script bound to a Sheet. Code:

Code.js

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index.html");
}

function doPost() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index.html");
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form" name="form" action="" method="POST">
      <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Looks simple enough right? Well when you click the submit button, the page redirect to a blank page.

I already know how to work around this behavior (by using script.run or even hackier by querying for the page's URL), but what I want is to know WHY things go wrong here, because what's the point of the doPost method if you can't even use it.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your page is served from another url `*.googleusercontent.com` for security reasons. The point of doPost method is you can post to the published url from your client(say, local Python script/nodeJs) anywhere on any server as long as you know the published url.

Comment: Can you describe this security reasons? I don't really understand how that work.

Comment: @snaplizard The actual url is `script.google.com/*` This is of domain google.com Technically, If it runs in Google.com, your script will have access to all Google cookies, even auth cookies of users visiting your web-app. Furthermore, You can do anything in the web page. To prevent this, Google put your web page in a iframe sourced from googleusercontent.com. So the top frame/parent can enforce certain rules and sanitize your code -as it runs inside a iframe. It can also inject arbitrary code(like `google` as in `google.script.run`).  I assume you already know how to workaround this.

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain in even more detail or is there some sort of documentation of this security feature? I can work around this, but not in a way that would allow a POST request to actually go through.

Comment: `that would allow a POST request to actually go through` You would need to change "action={url}", where url is the actual published url(script.google.com).  You can also use templated html: ``"action=<?=google.script.run.getUrl()?>"`` https://stackoverflow.com/a/49925624 getUrl is a server side function to retrieve the published url. Alternatively, See Sample [form](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms) Some documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content#redirects