# Google Apps Script: submit form + keep window content + make browser make an offer to save name/password

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script, web-applications

I´m trying to **submit** a HTML form while **keeping content of displayed page** on the screen and triggering **browser to make an offer to save username and password**.

```
<div id="signInForm" class="init">
  <form> 
    <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username">
    <br><br>
    <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
    <br><br>
    <button type="submit">Sign in</button>  
  </form>  
</div>
```

I´ve found out, that keeping content can be done various ways:
`preventDefault()`, `onsubmit="return false"`, `action="javascript:"`.

I successfully made work each of them. But each of them prevents browser (Chrome and Edge) from doing an offer of saving username and password. As long as I´ve learnt, an HTML form has a default behavior on submit which is navigating to the submission link. My theory is that the "navigating event" itself is what triggers an offer to save username and password. If I´m right, the only way to reach my goal is probably based on letting submission happen default way, while making browser keep the content somehow.

**Bur all I ever get after hitting `<button type="submit">Sign in</button>` is a blank page.**

**Is it even possible to overcome this simply in Apps Script? Or am I missing something basic?**

I tried to programmatically reload my page, but wasn´t able to do so. I don´t know how to work with `reload()`.

I´ve tried this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>
    <div id="x">I´m ORIGINAL page</div>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('x').innerHTML= 'I´m EDITED page';">edit page</button>
    <br>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Reload page</button>
  </body>
  
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      window.location.reload(true);
    }
  </script>
  
</html>
```

The snippet above works for me in Stackoverflow snippet editor, but it doesn´t work in my published GAS web app.

**EDIT** Probably close to solution for my problem is answer in this post: [Redirecting from doPost() in Google Web App, HTML form with App script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49922365/redirecting-from-dopost-in-google-web-app-html-form-with-app-script) where the author suggests this:

```
<form method="post" action="<?!= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() ?>">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

But it does nothing for me when copied and pasted and I don´t know how to implement it any other way. It looks general...

Comment: That last code snippet requires evaluating an intermediate `HtmlTemplate` to create the displayable `HtmlOutput`. Without seeing your server side `doGet` code, I can't say if you are doing that correctly. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#printing_scriptlets

Comment: @tehhowch I start with this: `function doGet() { return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate(); }`

Comment: Btw. can updating of `HtmlTemplate` be done other way than triggering from client side? Can I write a function that will f.i. use `append()` to `template`, but triggered from server side?

Comment: What happens on Submit after `preventDefault()`?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue when trying to avoid the page to reload to a blank page. The solution that worked for me was a piece of code that is on Google Apps Script Documentation (I leave the link [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms))

I hope this solution can help you to solve the blank reloading issue.

```html
<script>
      // Prevent forms from submitting.
      function preventFormSubmit() {
        var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
        for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
          forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
          });
        }
      }
      window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);

</script>
```